# Using restkit with core data, we wish to get updates (including deletions) from a web service and have restkit properly map to core data

Tags: ios, web-services, core-data, restkit

We are using restkit and core data to get data from a web service. Restkit can map the data to the core data objects when we do the initial processing to get the set of data into the core data objects in the beginning. However, later on, we don't want to get the whole set of data again from the web service, but just the updates (including deletions). We are having trouble doing this, even though we created a web service to provide just updates, given a timestamp.

Using RestKit 0.20.0 with core data

- Core data Model consists of ‘Category’ class.
- Web service provides only updated/deleted since the given ‘last update’ timestamp. `http://localhost:8080/Server/CategoryServlet?action=1&date=2014­09­01.`

The JSON response is of the sort
[image]

How do we use Restkit to update/delete corresponding core data objects while retaining the unmodified data? We tried using approaches like restkit's `deletionPredicate`, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I'd change the JSON to have 2 lists, 1 updated and 1 deleted. Now use 2 response descriptors to process each list separately. You need to do the deletion yourself. If an item is being deleted you don't need to send any more than the id (sending the name and description is wasteful).

Comment: Thanks Wain, will try that. It is disappointing to find that restkit can't handle deletions.

Comment: It has mechanisms to handle deletion, just not in the way that you have it configured. It's possible to add and you may want to discuss it on the google group / github.